# In Typescript is there a better way to represent the types of an object of arrays

Tags: typescript, types

I have an object which contains roles which are an array of rights which they grant e.g.

```
const allRoles = {
  user: [
    'right1'
  ],
  admin: [
    'right1',
    'right2'
  ],
} as const
```

If I wanted to get the types for user rights and admin rights I could do:

```
type userRights = Array<typeof allRoles.user[number]>
type adminRights = Array<typeof allRoles.admin[number]>
```

And to get the types for both I could do:

```
type RoleRights = userRights | adminRights
```

I don't need individual user rights or admin rights. Is there a way I can represent all of the available rights in on type declaration?

Similar to how if I wanted to create an array of all rights I could do:

```
const roleRights = new Map(Object.entries(allRoles))
```

Comment: Is it okay to get 'right1', 'right2'... to 'string'? or it has to be the 'right1' constant?

Comment: You mean like this? `type Rights = typeof allRoles[keyof typeof allRoles][number]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to infer your types using `as const` from the `allRoles` object, you could do the following:

```
const allRoles = {
  user: [
    'right1'
  ],
  admin: [
    'right1',
    'right2'
  ],
} as const

type RolesMap = typeof allRoles;
/*
{
  readonly user: readonly ["right1"];
  readonly admin: readonly ["right1", "right2"];
}
*/

type UserRoles = RolesMap['user']; // readonly ["right1"]
type AdminRoles = RolesMap['admin']; // readonly ["right1", "right2"]
type AllRoles = UserRoles | AdminRoles; // readonly ["right1"] | readonly ["right1", "right2"]
```

Note: This will make fixed types out of `['right1']` and `['right1', 'right2']`, you will notice this is therefore not automatically collapsed into something like `('right1' | 'right2')[]` which I imagine is what you are after.

However if you already know all of the rights in advance, which I imagine you likely do, architecturally it may make more sense to type the system the other way around, starting from the rights and building up to the map, e.g.

```
enum RightsEnum {
  right1 = 'right1',
  right2 = 'right2',
  right3 = 'right3',
  ...
}
enum RolesEnum {
  user = 'user',
  admin = 'admin'
}

// explicit
interface RolesMap {
  [RolesEnum.user]: [RightsEnum.right1],
  [RolesEnum.admin]: [RightsEnum.right1, RightsEnum.right2]
}

// generic
type RolesMap = Record<RolesEnum, RightsEnum>;

const allRoles: RolesMap = {
  user: [
    'right1'
  ],
  admin: [
    'right1',
    'right2'
  ],
}
```

Your "all rights" type would therefore just be `RightsEnum`

Answer (score 0):

```
type userRight = typeof allRoles.user[number]
type adminRight = typeof allRoles.admin[number]

type userRights = userRight[]
type adminRights = adminRight[]

type RoleRights = (userRight | adminRight)[]
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining how/why it answers the question / solves the problem.